# Importing a gensim doc2vec model in deeplearning4j

Tags: java, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec, deeplearning4j

I have trained a `doc2vec` model with `gensim` and like to import it into `Deeplearning4j` in order to deploy that model.

For `word2vec` models, I know that this is possible by saving the model with

```
model.wv.save_word2vec_format("word2vec.bin", binary=True)
```

and importing if in Java with

```
Word2Vec w2vModel = WordVectorSerializer.readWord2VecModel("word2vec.bin");
```

Is there a similar way to import a `doc2vec` model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `save_word2vec_format()` method saves just the word-vectors, not the full model.

If you were to use Gensim's `.save()` to save the full model, it'd use Python's native serialization - so any Java code to read it would have to understand that format before rearranging relevant properties into the DL4J objects.

I don't see anything in the docs for [DL4J's `ParagraphVectors` class docs](https://deeplearning4j.org/api/latest/org/deeplearning4j/models/paragraphvectors/ParagraphVectors.html) suggesting it can read Gensim-formatted models, so I doubt there's any built-in support.

It's theoretically possible that some Python code could be written to dump all the relevant subparts of the model in forms amenable to reading in Java, then patching into a Dl4J model, or for Java code to be written to understand the Python serialized objects – but that'd require some familiarity with both the Gensim & DL4J source code.

(If the `toJson()` & `fromJson()` methods in DL4J work with full model representations – which isn't clear from the docs, and would be an extremely bloated format for the bulk of the model state – that'd likely make the model-translation a little easier, as it'd provide a straightforward template for what some new Python code would need to write-out.)